# Which Library to use: Smack or aSmack?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I have been going through many answered questions, Blogs and Websites regarding which library to use for Android Chat Application(Smack/aSmack) . In many places it is mentioned that aSmack is the Android compatible version, but then some Webpages say that aSmack Development/Maintenance is stopped and we need to use Smack going forward. I'm not able figure out which one to use. Please tell me the download links as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a look at the aSmack commit history at https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/commits/master. The recent commit is just a few days ago. This doesn't look like the development has stopped. There can also be recent snapshots of the upcoming 4.0.0 version of aSmack found at http://asmack.freakempire.de/SNAPSHOTS/

This doesn't look like a project that has stopped. You should notify the author of the website stating that aSmack development has stopped.

BTW, plain Smack does not work on Android. You have to use aSmack.

Answer (score 0):

The user who searching the answer to this question in this time:

The aSmack is obsolete, and the repository has the information. ([info](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/blob/master/README.markdown)).

Now use the Smack: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack